# Amcharts: Output balloonText for type XY

Tags: javascript, amcharts, popup-balloons

When I'm pointing at a point in the chart, information pops up like this:

[image]

But when there is a pile around, then nothing happens:

[image]

I know that this can not be done with the standard means of outputting `balloonText` with the type of XY, but maybe there are non-standard solutions?

Do you know any alternative?
Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm since I'm not sure what you mean about "pile around", is the cursor in the second screenshot not on a point in the XY chart's dataProvider? If so then there isn't a way to display information about a position on the line if it doesn't correspond to a point.

Comment: thanks for replying, I'll have to use type: `serial`